# How to include order summery section on a phtml page?

Tags: custom-template

How can we include the order summary section on a custom .phtml page?

Comment: can you please more elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: add below code in checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_text_summary"
               template="Vendor_Module::checkout/custom_text.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Step 2:

In custom_text.phtml file add the below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.helloworld = '<?php echo __('Hello world'); ?>';
</script>
```

Step 3:
override the file you want.

app\design\Theme\Theme_Name\Magento_Checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary\item\details.html

add below code your file

```
   <!-- Custom Text -->
   <tr class="custom-field">
     <td class="myClass">
       <span data-bind="html: helloworld"></span>
   </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: thanks, but I am not asking to add custom text in the order summary, but my question is how we can show order summary on a custom page.